Expo React Native ts Nativewind ( (NOBRIDGE) ERROR Error: Exception in HostFunction: Unable to convert string to floating point value: "large" )
I have problem with my expo react native with nativewind project,
when I upgrade the expo SDK from 51 to 52 and test the app on actual device iPhone 12 pro via expo app downloaded from app store
it builds successfully via command below
npx expo start -c
but shows error below
IOS Error
(NOBRIDGE) LOG  Bridgeless mode is enabled
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Error: Exception in HostFunction: Unable to convert string to floating point value: "large"   


This error is located at:
    in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))        
    in Animated(Anonymous)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)   
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer) 
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)       
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CssInterop.View)
    in CssInterop.View (created by Animated(View))       
    in Animated(View) (created by Background)
    in Background (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider) 
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)     
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CssInterop.View)
    in CssInterop.View (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)     
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by RootNavigator)
    in RootNavigator (created by App)
    in ThemeProvider
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in QueryClientProvider (created by App)
    in I18nextProvider (created by App)
    in ThemeProvider (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CssInterop.View)
    in CssInterop.View (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CssInterop.View)
    in CssInterop.View (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CssInterop.View)
    in CssInterop.View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CssInterop.View)
    in CssInterop.View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)

Android Error
 (NOBRIDGE) LOG  Bridgeless mode is enabled
 (NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNCWebView' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary.Bridgeless mode: true. TurboModule interop: true. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":[],"TurboModules":["PlatformConstants","LogBox","SourceCode","Appearance","AppState","AccessibilityInfo","DeviceInfo","BlobModule","WebSocketModule","DevSettings","DevToolsSettingsManager","Networking","DevLoadingView","ImageLoader","SoundManager","IntentAndroid","DeviceEventManager","NativeReactNativeFeatureFlagsCxx","NativeAnimatedModule","ReanimatedModule","RNGestureHandlerModule","StatusBarManager","StatusBarManager","I18nManager","RNCAsyncStorage"],"NotFound":["NativePerformanceCxx","NativePerformanceObserverCxx","AccessibilityManager","RedBox","BugReporting","HeadlessJsTaskSupport","LinkingManager","RNCSafeAreaContext","FrameRateLogger","KeyboardObserver","RNSModule","PlatformLocalStorage","RNC_AsyncSQLiteDBStorage","RNCWebView"]}
 (NOBRIDGE) WARN   React Native's New Architecture is always enabled in Expo Go, but it is not explicitly enabled your project app config. This may lead to unexpected behavior when you create a production or development build. Set "newArchEnabled": true in your app.json.
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/new-architecture/

How to fix the above error, best regards.
I tried to upgrade all libraries and start with clean build, and the error still appear the same on Android and IOS.

I found the solution for this
you need to
run npx expo-doctor
install expo-doctor if not installed
then follow what expo doctor logs for upgrading libraries and removing libraries that is not managed by expo for me
I have to do below commands
yarn remove @types/react-native
yarn add metro@^0.81.0 metro-resolver@^0.81.0 metro-config@^0.81.0
my expo version is 52
my react native version is 0.76.2 (npx npm view react-native version)

Run the following commands to diagnose and fix any dependency issues in your Expo project:
npx expo-doctor
npx expo install --check

These commands will identify errors and resolve any dependency mismatches.
If you’re using Expo SDK 52, note that it introduces a new architecture. To avoid issues related to the old architecture, ensure that your app.json includes the following configuration:
"expo": {
  "newArchEnabled": true
}

This setting ensures that your project explicitly uses the new architecture, aligning it with the latest updates in Expo SDK 52.
